# what's the difference between stackexchange 1.0 and 2.0?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stackexchange-2.0

Besides licensing/hosting, is there any technical difference?

Comment: Yeah, new features in version 2.0 are not exist in version 1.0

Comment: Let's see, carry the 1...I figure there's exactly a 1.000000 difference

Comment: Not sure if this should be closed as a duplicate of [What was Stack Exchange 1.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299101/335251)...

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.0 runs a much older version of the codebase <strike>and does not support rich themeing</strike>.

Comment: Well, all the theming is just CSS, there's nothing inherently more or less supported in 1.0 vs 2.0 with regards to styling, just more features/stuff.

Comment: @Nick: Even the fancier SE2 prod themes?

Comment: Yeah sure, all CSS and images...the sites themselves are all identical HTML :)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much all of this:

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

And then some...